# Solving algorithm in Java for ln(N!)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need to calculate `ln(n!)`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
    public void fact() {
        System.out.println("Enter The integer");
        Scanner ns = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = ns.nextInt();
if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println("Factorial is " + 1);
System.out.println("Log OF 0 is Undefined!! ");
}
if(n!=0) {
        double a=1;
        for(     int z=1; z<=n;z++) {
            a*=z;

        }
        System.out.println("Fact is"+a);



System.out.println("Log of ln(N!) is "+ Math.log(a));
}
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App ap = new App();
        ap.fact();

    }
}
```

I don't know what the heck is wrong with Maths.log function. Am I doing right? It's not giving me an appropriate answer.

Comment: Please describe what exactly is going wrong with your code

Comment: Your code is fine, though it would fail for relatively small values of `n`, since `n!` overflows for small n.

Comment: @amit Log function is not giving the appropriate answer when i pass the factorial through math.log().

Comment: @Eran i had changed the variable to long& double but still its not locking on the right answer. :|

Comment: @M.UsmanSiddiqui What values of `n` are you testing?

Comment: @M.UsmanSiddiqui With double, n! will result in infinity for n>170

Comment: @Eran i had initially used 6 as base value for n to calculate factorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you encounter into an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) here.

Note that n! grows very fast, and for any n>12, you will get a number that cannot fit in an integer, you should probably think of a clever way to not fully calculate n! and still get the correct result.

Hint below:

<sub><sub>log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)</sub></sub>

Comment: @M.UsmanSiddiqui `long` will overflow as well quickly, double suffers from inaccuracies for large values due to floating point arithmetic issues. Think of a way to calculate it without explicitly calculating n!, it can be done. If you fail to think of it - the hint in my answer should really help.

Comment: does overflowing depends on my ram or what ? Sorry that's an out of topic question but still it would help in my understanding's. Regards.

Comment: @M.UsmanSiddiqui No, it depends on how many bits are representing the integer, in java it's 32 for `int` and 64 for `long`. Since `n!` grows really fast, it quickly gets out of range of these types.

Comment: no it does not, its the size of long that matters which is fixed for java

Answer (score 1):

Your task is a topic for Stirling's approximation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: could you please inbox me your email id? I wanna talk! please.